# Why Spark Job executed on master server only during the Cleaned accumulator steps

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have launched a cluster of spark using 3 EC2 instances of c4.2xlarge (15GB RAM/ 8 Cores)  type let's name then as A, B, and C.

Configuring A:
I have started it as a master-server.sh

`start-master.sh`

And on this cluster i have only launched 3 executors. with the following command

`start-slave.sh <master-uri> -c 3`

Configuring B and C:

I have created 8 executors on both of the instances by running the following command on each instance.

`start-slave.sh <master-uri> -c 8`

Now My code is following:

```
# Loading wiki dumps files.
lines = spark.read.text(sys.argv[1]).rdd.map(lambda r: r[0].encode("utf-8"))

# Running word count algorithm. and selecting with count as 1.
counts = lines.flatMap(lambda x: x.lower().split(' ')) \
              .map(lambda x: (x, 1)) \
              .reduceByKey(add) \
                .filter(lambda x: x[1] == 1) \
                .map(lambda (x,y): x)

# Making Dataframe from RDD.
df = lines.map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF(['raw_sentence'])

# Tokenizing using spark ml API.
fl = Tokenizer(inputCol="raw_sentence", outputCol="words")
df = fl.transform(df).select("words")

# Removing Stopwords. Pay attention I am converting counts to list iterator.
fl = StopWordsRemover(inputCol="words", outputCol="filtered")
fl.setStopWords(fl.getStopWords() + list(counts.toLocalIterator()))
df = fl.transform(df).select("filtered")
```

Initially when I started the Job. My server A, B and C were utilising all the cores. But then After some time my B and C cores won't use any memory 
or cores and at this stage following were the logs:

> 17/09/08 20:31:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_0_piece0 on
>   172.31.35.55:45288 in memory (size: 25.0 KB, free: 6.2 GB) 17/09/08 20:31:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_0_piece0 on
>   172.31.44.209:39094 in memory (size: 25.0 KB, free: 6.2 GB) 17/09/08 20:31:54 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 51
>
> 17/09/08 21:13:51 WARN HeartbeatReceiver: Removing executor 2 with no
>   recent heartbeats: 232069 ms exceeds timeout 120000 ms 17/09/08
>   21:26:15 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 2 on 172.31.44.209:
>   Executor heartbeat timed out after 232069 ms
>   17/09/08 21:27:09 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error sending result
>   RpcResponse{requestId=8270848140270032673,
>   body=NioManagedBuffer{buf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=47
>   cap=64]}} to /172.31.44.209:33418; closing connection
>   java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

[image]

Line 47 of my code is the second last line of above code which is following:

```
fl.setStopWords(fl.getStopWords() + list(counts.toLocalIterator()))
```

Custom Configuration are:
SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=12G

Rest were defaults.

So why on line 47 tasks were not running as distributed?
And Why it crashed even though I have Extra resources available, especially RAM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RDD.toLocalIterator` fetches a single partition at the time. So the execution pattern will be similar to this:

1. A single partition is computed. This may require activity from a single executor (no wide dependencies) or multiple executors.
2. Data is fetched to driver and local thread starts to iterate. Driver is active, the rest of code is idle.
3. Once the end of the chunk is reached, and there are more partitions to follow, driver will request next partition (go to 1.).

Since you convert iterator to `list` you can as well `collect`. Memory consumption will be the same (and possibly lead to failure) but all nodes will compute their parts without pauses.